# Using two "and"s to list a profession followed by two sub fields of another profession

Tags: meaning, grammaticality

I have the following part of a sentence:

> Aerospace engineer and rocket designer and engineer Wernher von Braun [. . .]

My intention is to convey that Wernher von Braun was—among other things—the following:

- An Aerospace Engineer
- A Rocket Designer
- A **Rocket** Engineer

Does the this sentence correctly convey that Mr. Braun held those three titles, or does "and engineer" imply a generic engineer and not specifically a "rocket engineer"? If the latter, how should it be written instead to coincide with the former?

I could reword the sentence like so:

> Aerospace engineer, rocket designer, and rocket engineer Wernher von Braun [. . .]

However, I feel that that is more redundant, and less appealing to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latter example is better and more appealling, it also makes more sense - with so many ‘engineers’ in the first one, one is left wondering er - engineer - didn’t you say that *already*?

Whereas with the second one, it’s more like ‘oh - *rocket* engineer and *rocket* designer ... how coool!’